# Adding an extra directory in Rails tmp directory on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to add an extra directory inside the rails tmp directory.

```
#Config/initializers/prince.rb

begin
  Dir.mkdir(Rails.root.join('tmp/prince'))
rescue Exception => e
  # Directory already exists
  puts "Error creating tmp/prince directory"
  puts e.message
end
```

Doing it on my local machine it works just fine. On heroku it breaks with:

```
Error creating tmp/prince directory
No such file or directory - /tmp/build_1c02fc8d-e053-46c6-8449-57036a89044e/tmp/prince
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I also had that problem. The best way I found was to create the folders on your development machine and push it to Heroku. 
First you have to remove /tmp from your .gitignore file then..

```
mkdir tmp

touch tmp/.keep

mkdir tmp/new_folder

touch tmp/new_folder/.keep
```

The .keep file created is empty but necessary to be able to upload it. Empty folders are ignored by git.

After your finished, add /tmp back to your .gitignore so you don't accidentally push any /tmp/* files to Heroku.

Comment: Good start, but the default in `.gitignore` is to ignore `/tmp` so this will not work yet.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `Dir.mktmpdir` to create tmp dir on heroku if you want to write something in it.

```
def apply_watermark
  Dir.mktmpdir do |tmpdir|
  ...
  save_watermarked_file(watermarked_local_file)
end
```